# Must token contract transfer all tokens to crowdsale contract before it can sell them?

Tags: truffle, erc-20, javascript, crowdsale

I notice that on the standard tests for crowdsale contracts in Openzeppelin, they transfer the tokens from the Token contract to the Crowdsale Contract:

```
context('once deployed', async function () {
      beforeEach(async function () {
        this.tokensale = await TokenSale.new(rate, wallet, this.token.address);
        await this.token.transfer(this.tokensale.address, tokenSupply);
      });
```

However [other examples](https://hashnode.com/post/the-2018-guide-to-writing-and-testing-real-world-crowdsale-contracts-cjcs8dfes00apmdwthw03c2jq) do not do this. So I wonder why this is necessary, if internally the `CrowdSale` contract uses the token contract to send the tokens:

```
function _deliverTokens(
        address beneficiary,
        uint256 tokenAmount
    )
    internal
    {
        _token.safeTransfer(beneficiary, tokenAmount);
    }
```

In the function above `_token` is the IERC20 interface of the Token contract. Can some one explain this a bit better than [this page](https://openzeppelin.org/api/docs/learn-about-crowdsales.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to send all tokens to a crowdsale contract upon creation. You may do whatever best fits your business model.

For example, a common scenario is to sell 25% of the tokens in the sale and retain the remainder. In this case, you will create 25% of the tokens into the crowdsale contract and 75% into your own wallet.

The contract above delivers the tokens, as expected. `_token.safeTransfer(beneficiary, tokenAmount);` is saying that this contract will transfer tokens *from this contract* to the beneficiary. The key to this statement is that the tokens live in the crowdsale contract, or else `safeTransfer()` will throw. As you mentioned, `_token` is the IERC20 interface to the contract.

The test that you referenced is a `beforeEach` function, which *resets* the contracts upon *before each* test. This is simply a convenient way to fill a contract with tokens to test. The tests written for this code are specific to the token distribution, thus it is feasible to send all tokens over.